# Sklearn train_test_split fails on 2d vector

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import sklearn.model_selection as skl_ms
import numpy as np

A = np.random.normal(0, 1, [1, 100]);
(A_train, A_test) = skl_ms.train_test_split(A);
A_train.shape #--> Answer is (0, 100)
A_test.shape #---> Answer is (1, 100)
```

Uh... is this desired functionality? I don't even understand why numpy lets arrays with 0 for the first dimension exist.

Numpy 1.14.2, sklearn 0.19.1, python 3.5.5

Comment: When you only have 1 sample, how do you intend to split the data into train and test?

Comment: I have posted this as an [issue on scikit github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11028), to get more meaningful response about the working.

Comment: @VivekKumar Well, the function works properly when you pass it a 1-dimensional numpy vector, which is why I'd expect it to also work properly for a 2d vector.

Comment: Yes, but what do you expect as results when you have 1 row only? How will you divide it into train and test?

Answer (score 1):

When defining data sets variables are represented in columns and observations in rows. So, if you have three independent variables, one dependent variable and 20 measurements, your data set would be represented as a 20 x 4 matrix - that is 20 rows and 4 columns. By default, train_test_split splits the data set into a 0.75 fraction of measurements as a training set and a 0.25 fraction as a testing set. For the example with 20 x 4 data set, the split will be 15 x 4 for training and 5 x 4 for testing. As for you code, here is what happens if the dimensions are reversed:

```
import sklearn.model_selection as skl_ms
import numpy as np

A = np.random.normal(0, 1, [100, 1]);
(A_train, A_test) = skl_ms.train_test_split(A);

A_train.shape
Out[105]: (75, 1)

A_test.shape
Out[106]: (25, 1)
```